# Fluid UI react - Top nav bar best practice

Tags: uinavigationbar, office-ui-fabric, office-ui-fabric-react

Looking through the components, there isn't a top navigation in horizontal format. I supposed it could be built from the components offered but I'm looking for best practice. Is there a sample or doc from Fluid UI that discusses this common scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I think the [horizontal stack](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/stack) is the component/style that would work.